# how to retrieve TextBox control's ClientID within the ListView's ItemDataBound event?

Tags: asp.net

I am having trouble retrieving a TextBox control's ClientID value from a ListView control.
I thought this syntax would return me the ClientID fine(very strange):
**((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("amount")).ClientID;**

but it keeps throwing this exception:

**"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"**

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Below is my code:
aspx:

```
<asp:ListView ID="categories" runat="server" 
    ClientIDRowSuffix="ID"
     ItemPlaceholderID="categoryItem"
     DataKeyNames="ID" onitemdatabound="categories_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>             
            <div class="category">
                <asp:TextBox ID="amount" runat="server" />                   
            </div>
     </ItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

codebehind:

```
public string AmountTextBoxClientID { get; set; }

    protected string GetAmountTextBoxClientID()
     {
         return this.AmountTextBoxClientID;
     }


protected void categories_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
     {
         switch (e.Item.ItemType)
         {
             case ListViewItemType.DataItem:
                 
                TextBox amountTextBox = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("amount");//this line excutes without any error
                 amountTextBox.Text = categoryAmount.ToString("C");
                 amountTextBox.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
                
                this.AmountTextBoxClientID = amountTextBox.ClientID; //this line keeps throwing the OutOfRange exception
                 break;
         }
      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Im afraid I cant pinpoint your problem but i drew up a page based on what you've given and pasted it below.  It does NOT error.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">
    public string AmountTextBoxClientID { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("column1");
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = "some data";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        ListView1.DataSource = dt;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tbAmount = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("amount");
        this.AmountTextBoxClientID = tbAmount.ClientID;
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" onitemdatabound="ListView1_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="amount" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Christian,Thanks for looking at my problem.  I think I figured out my problem.  I was not binding my datasource in the Page_Load event; I was calling the Databind() method in my user's control's base.bind() override method.  My work around for this issue was to use this code after the the ListView control was completely loaded on the page:     foreach (ListViewItem li in this.categories.Items)
            {
                TextBox tbox = (TextBox)li.FindControl("amount");
                this.AmountTextBoxClientID = tbox.ClientID;
            }